# How To Set up Call Hold and Pick Up In Asterisk

Tags: asterisk

I am quit new in asterisk.

My problem is: I have to implement call hold and pick up in asterisk.

Let's say we have an incoming call called incomingCallA.
As an operator I want to hold incomingCallA for a while to deal with other works, then come back soon, If i am not come back, others operator will pick up my held call.

I have done some researches that told me:
Call hold is sip client function, dont need to changes at asterisk server.

I can use call parking to dial to others operator if i am not come back.

Please help me to about the solution to deal with above problem.

Many thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Simplest for begginer is create 100 conference rooms using Meetme after that just send to first availible room and record room number.

You can forward call using Transfer AMI function.